# Update multiple rows in once. based on id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a variable, $ids
It is a , separated string so it can be   $ids = "1"  or $ids = "1, 3, 7, 8"

What i want to do is update the database based on these values so i have :

```
   $query = "UPDATE Fields SET Value = '1'   WHERE Id IN '$ids'";
```

And also:

```
   $query = "UPDATE Fields SET Value = '1'   WHERE Id '$ids'";
```

What is the best way to update the database, should i split the string in to an array, and then do a for each loop? or is there a better way?

Comment: which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Is the solution above not working?

Comment: phpmyadmin ? not sure   Nope the solution above is what i have tryd

Comment: phpmyadmin is not a DBMS.

Comment: implode(",", array_filter(array_map("intval", explode(",",$ids))));  should make sure all of you ids are non-zero integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the fact that it's wide open to SQL Injection, this line **works** for one or many id's:

```
$query = "UPDATE Fields SET Value = '1'   WHERE Id IN ($ids)";
```

Now, to keep yourself from SQL Injection attacks, which is obviously up to you, you'd want to explode that array and send multiple update statements like this:

```
$query = "UPDATE Fields SET Value = '1'   WHERE Id = :Id";
```

Comment: shouldn't that be
$query = "UPDATE Fields SET Value = '1'   WHERE Id IN ($ids)";

Comment: @BarbaraLaird, yeah, copy and paste error. I was editing while you were commenting. :D

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing inherently wrong with using an `IN` clause here.  Any `WHERE` clause works for an `UPDATE` statement.  You'll just want to treat the numbers as a list of values instead of a string.  Something like this:

```
$query = "UPDATE Fields SET Value = '1' WHERE Id IN ($ids)";
```

The really important part is how you *get* the `$ids` value into the query in the first place.  You don't show that in the question, but you'll want to make sure you're not opening yourself to a SQL injection vulnerability.  Make sure you're properly sanitizing inputs and using prepared statements.  How prepared statements handle lists of values vs. individual values is up to the data access technology being used.

Comment: It is a post value, havent got a check in it yet just trying to get the query right.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
$query = "UPDATE Fields SET Value = '1' WHERE Id IN ($ids)";
```

Where `$ids` should be formatted als 1,2,3,4. Don't forget to check them before execution (SQL Injection).

Comment: Thx i tryd it but it didnt work it worked when putting IN after Id.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, that's what a wanted to post ;-)